# Subset of an infinite set with same cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Let $A$ be an infinite set. Show that there is a subset $B\subseteq A$ such that $|B|=|A-B|=|A|$. I've tried using Zorn's lemma with $P(A)$ and  $\subset$ and got nowhere. I would like a hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:** Turn the question around. Use Zorn's lemma to prove there is a bijection between $B$ and $B\times\Bbb \{0,1\}$, or $B\times\Bbb N$ or $B\times B$ (either one works out).

Comment: Would you mind showing the proof in details?

Comment: You can find more details elsewhere on the site, e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1041731/prove-that-if-a-is-an-infinite-set-then-a-times-2-is-equipotent-to-a