# Show that an infinite set $C$ is equipotent to its cartesian product $C\times C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

So, as the title says I'd like to give a proof of the fact that if $C$ is an infinite set then it is equipotent or equivalent to its cartesian product $C\times C$ using Zorn's Lemma (and of course some of its implications like the fact that $C$ has an infinite countable subset which I think might be very useful).

The main problem that I have is that I'm not supposed to use any theorem or result involving cardinal numbers since I'm still taking an elementary set theory course which hasn't covered that topic yet and all the proofs that I've read so far use cardinals arithmetic at some point.

Another thing that I think might be useful is a lemma which was proved via Zorn's Lemma in an answer to the question  [Prove that if $A$ is an infinite set then $A \times 2$ is equipotent to $A$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1041731/prove-that-if-a-is-an-infinite-set-then-a-times-2-is-equipotent-to-a) which states that given the infinite set $C$ there exists a non-empty set $B$ such that $B\times \mathbb{N}$ is equipotent to $C$. Then it suffices to give a bijection from $(B\times \mathbb{N})$ $\times$ $(B\times \mathbb{N})$ to $B\times \mathbb{N}$

So, any suggestion on the direct proof (without cardinals, unfortuntely) via Zorn's Lemma or an actual bijection from $(B\times \mathbb{N})$ $\times$ $(B\times \mathbb{N})$ to $B\times \mathbb{N}$ would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10):

You can't give an actual bijection, since the theorem you are trying to prove is in fact equivalent to the axiom of choice and Zorn's lemma. So for some cases, like $\Bbb N$ or so we can write it down, but in general we can't.

You need to appeal to Zorn's lemma three times here:

1. Every infinite set has a countably infinite subset, which is quite straightforward.
2. If $X$ is an infinite set, then $|X|+|X|=|X|$. This can be done by considering $(A,f)$ such that $A\subseteq X$ and $f\colon A\times\{0,1\}\to A$ is a bijection, ordered by extension on both coordinates.

   From this you can prove directly that $|X\times\mathbb N|=|X|$ for every infinite set $X$ (you can also try and prove that directly with Zorn's lemma, but I don't see an easy way to do so).
3. Now we can prove $|X|^2=|X|$ for all infinite $X$, by considering the partial order whose elements are $(A,f)$ such that $A\subseteq X$ and $f\colon A\times A\to A$ is a bijection. Again, order this by extension on both coordinates.

   Now if $(A,f)$ is a maximal element, then $|A|=|X|$ or else there is a countably infinite set $B\subseteq X\setminus A$. Then you can prove that: $$X\times X=A\times A\cup A\times B\cup B\times A\cup B\times B$$ and conclude via cardinal arithmetic and the previous steps that $|X|=|A|$ after all. Therefore $|X|^2=|X|$.

While this path to a proof does rely on some cardinal arithmetic, it is relatively painless. The only difficult part is showing that $|X\times\Bbb N|=|X|$, which is an application of induction on the existing bijection $f\colon X\times\{0,1\}\to X$. Zorn's lemma won't be as helpful there.

Comment: This is a terrible truth of mathematics: "entirely elementary answer that avoids such and such technicalities" is almost always much more complicated and harder to understand, since you end up developing a half-assed version of said technicalities inside the proof. This is Greenspun's 10th law for mathematics.

Comment: What do you mean by “application of induction”? Induction will help us in any finite case but you can’t extend it to infinity.

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku: The recursion theorem provides. Because we have a given function to start with.

Comment: How do you use the countably infinite set to prove the equality?

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku: I'm not sure what you mean. The proof essentially argues that $X\setminus A$ is finite.

Comment: But how would you make that argument? It would work when you are proving that the addition law for cardinals, but I can not see it working for product…

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku: I still don't think I follow the problem. I agree that is not written in the most ideal way, and I'd probably give a more robust argument nearly a decade of experience in writing mathematical proofs later. But still...

Comment: The problem is(if I am not mistaken) that it is possible to have a countably(or even a set of cardinality less than $A$) infinite set $B\subseteq X\setminus A$, and still have that $A$ is maximal.

Comment: The proof can be fixed by arguing that $X\setminus A$ has to have cardinality less than $A$. However in this proof nowhere do we make use of the fact that $A\times \mathbb{N}\equiv A$ only that $A+A\equiv A$.

Comment: To give a concrete example consider $\mathbb{R}$, then $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{N}$ is maximal even though $\mathbb{N}$ is not finite.

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku: Sorry, I'm just super busy in the last few days and didn't have time to properly read and think about this. I should have time tomorrow, so please ping me again tomorrow to see (in case I haven't already answered you).

Comment: Here is an IMO correct proof fully written out:
Fix an infinite set $X$, we know that $|X|+|X|\equiv |X|$, we prove that $|X\times X|=|X|$ below:

Consider the partial order whose elements are $(A,f)$ such that $A\subseteq X$ and $f: A\times A\to A$ is a bijection. By Zorn's lemma this partial order has a maximal element $(M,g)$, we show that $|M|=|X|$, which implies the desired conclusion as follows: (cont...)

Comment: (cont...) suppose it were not the case, clearly we must then have  $|M|<|X|$, this means that there exists a subset $B\subseteq X \setminus M$ such that $|B|=|M|$, using the fact $|M|+|M|=|M|$ and $|M\times M|=|M|$, it is not hard to come up with a function $g$ such that $(M\cup B, g)$ contradicts the maximalilty of $(M,f).$

Comment: The purpose of this comment is to serve as a "ping".