# $|A^2|=|A|$ for every infinite $A$ iff Axiom of Choice holds.

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I've seen this assertion in a few comments around the site, and I found the answer to the $\rightarrow$ implication [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56466/for-every-infinite-s-s-s-times-s-implies-the-axiom-of-choice)

Does anyone know a (hopefully simple) proof of the $\leftarrow$ implication?

Comment: Prove it by induction on $\kappa = |A|$. Well-order $\kappa \times \kappa$ by first considering $\max(x,y)$ and then applying the lexicographic ordering. Check that all initial segments have cardinality $< \kappa$.

Comment: More precisely: given AC, every cardinal $\kappa =\aleph_{\alpha}$ for some $\alpha$, so prove by (transfinite) induction on $\alpha$ that the order type on $\kappa \times\kappa$ has length $\kappa$. The ordering is $(a,b) \prec (c,d) \iff $ either $\max(a,b) < \max(c,d)$, or $\max(a,b) = \max(c,d)$ and $(a,b)$ precedes $(c,d)$ lexicographically.

Comment: This has more than a handful duplicates. Do you want one with ordinals, or one with Zorn's lemma?

Comment: I'd prefer to avoid ordinals. I couldn't find duplicates.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1043350/show-that-an-infinite-set-c-is-equipotent-to-its-cartesian-product-c-times-c should be an answer; although the nice argument is with ordinals. I can't close as a duplicate since there are no *upvoted* answers, though.

Comment: (Frankly, the proof via Zorn is incredibly convoluted and requires several additional proofs; the proof that for every infinite ordinal $|\alpha|^2=|\alpha|$ is relatively straightforward and beautiful.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks for the edits to your answer, it made it much clearer. Do you have a link for the proof using ordinals at hand? I know *very* little about ordinals, but perhaps I understand it.

Comment: Sure, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/608538/godels-pairing-function-and-proving-c-cc-for-aleph-cardinals has both a summary of the ordinal-based proof (with an expanded link) as well a variant of Zorn's argument which avoids choice (namely we make an appeal to a Zorn-like principle, but we can prove that the partial order we're interested in has a maximal element without really using the axiom of choice).