# Relation between cardinality of linear span and cardinality of field

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, set-theory

I am trying to prove the following statement

> Let $V$ be vector space over an infinite field $F$, and $S$ be an at most countable subset of $V$. Then $|L(S)| = |F|$, where $|S|$ denotes the cardinality of $S$ and $L(S)$ is the linear span of $S$.

Can you please help me to construct a bijection between $L(S)$ and $F$, or give me another idea?

Comment: $S$ must contain at least one nonzero vector. Then, first prove that $|L(S)|\ge|F|.$

Comment: For the reverse inequality, use that ($\forall n\in\Bbb N$) $|F^n|=|F|$ (this requires the axiom of choice if I remember well)

Comment: @AnneBauval could you perhaps give some indication of why you think this needs axiom of choice (or perhaps a name of something that I can look up) because it seems to me at least that one does not need axiom of choice for sets that are countable or have a cardinality of the continuum, so it would be interesting to see if/why it breaks down

Comment: $|A^2|=|A|$ is easy to prove indeed without AC when $A=\Bbb N$ or $\Bbb R.$ For the general case I do not "think" AC is necessary. I only vaguely remember. @Carlyle

Comment: @Carlyle I found this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1617795/a2-a-for-every-infinite-a-iff-axiom-of-choice-holds?noredirect=1

Comment: You can prove the statement without constructing an explicit bijection.  You do need to assume that $S \neq \{ 0 \}$, but with that assumption, it's quite easy to show that $\vert L(S) \vert \geq \vert F \vert$.  Then use the fact that $S$ is at most countable to prove the other inequality.

Comment: @AnneBauval thanks!

Comment: Robert's comment was more or less included in my 2 first ones above. In the first one: not only do you need to assume that $S \neq \{ 0 \}.$ It must also be $\ne\varnothing.$

Answer (score 0):

Note that:
$$L(S)=\{\sum_{i=1}^n a_iv_i:v_i\in S,a_i\in F,n\in\mathbb{N}\}=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}
\{\sum_{i=1}^n a_iv_i:v_i\in S,a_i\in F\}=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n$$

For each $A_n$, you have a surjection $S^n\times F^n\to A_n$ given by:
$$(v_1,\ldots,v_n,a_1,\ldots,a_n)\to\sum_{i=1}^n a_iv_i$$
So $|A_n|\leq |S^n\times F^n|$. It is clear that also $|F|\leq |A_n|$.
As $F$ is infinite and $S$ at most countable:
$$|F|\leq |A_n|\leq |S^n\times F^n|=\max\{|S^n|,|F^n|\}=|F^n|=|F|$$
Therefore $|A_n|=|F|$. A countable union of such sets again has the same cardinality as $F$, since $F$ is infinite.

Comment: Your map $A_n\to S^n\times F^n$ is not well defined, and there is no obvious bijection between these 2 sets. The best you can do is define a surjection in the other direction.

Comment: You can moreover freely improve and include my 2 comments above.

Comment: @AnneBauval Fixed it. For some reason I thought the question said $S$ is a linearly independent set.

Comment: Even so, there wouldn't have been any obvious bijection between these 2 sets. + There remain things to exploit in my 2 initial comments above.