# Countable subset of an infinite set

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

So currently I have a problem on the following question:
Let $A$ be an infinite set. Show that there is a countable subset $B\subseteq A$ such that $|A|=|A-B|$ as asked here: [Subset of an infinite set with same cardinality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/658552/subset-of-an-infinite-set-with-same-cardinality).

The construction of a set $B$ seems pretty easy (One thing I have noticed is that $B \neq A$). But showing that there is bijective function with $A-B \rightarrow A$ is where I am currently stuck. We cannot use a slightly altered version of $id_A$ as there is no good way to "hit" the missing elements in $A$ I guess.

So my question is: How can I show that there is such a bijective function or how am I able to construct it?

As this is homework I would appreciate hints over full solutions for now.

Comment: @JonasMeyer I think the first paragraph is meant to say "$\vert A\vert=\vert A-B\vert$; they get it right in their second paragraph ("$A-B\rightarrow A$").

Comment: Are u sure? The question states that $A$ should be infinite - what e.g is with A being the reals and B being all even integers? As all even integers are of the same Cardinality as the integers itself shouldn't A-B still of the same Cardinality as the reals?

Comment: @JonasMeyer Thanks for pointing that out!  English is not my native language

Comment: @JonasMeyer Good point about the title.

Comment: @NoahSchweber and thanks for pointing that out too!

Comment: Someone better versed than me in the Axiom of Choice answer me this:  Without the axiom of choice, Do we know that infinite sets must have countable subsets?

Comment: @fleablood: No, we don't. On the contrary: without the Axiom of Choice, there may exist infinite Dedekind-finite sets, such as _amorphous sets_, which are infinite sets that do not have two disjoint infinite subsets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\{ a_i : i \in N \}$  a denumberable subset of A
with for all distinct j,k in N, $a_j \not = a_k$.
Let $B = \{ a_{2j} : j \in N \}$.

A bijection f from A - B onto A is $a_{2j-1}$ to $a_j$, for j in N
and the identity map for the other points.

Comment: So it is fine to say that if $B$ is of the same Cardinality as the denumerable subset it follows that $A-B$ is also of the same Cardinality as $A$?

Comment: Heck no!  You have to prove that by constructing a bijection and while you are at it use the axiom of choice to show the existence of the denumberable subset (notice edit).

Comment: Yeah thats true that is what i did earlier instead of just saying it. I constructed a function between the enumarable set and $B$ called $f$ with $f(a_i)=f(a_{2i})$ which is bijective and then constructed a function which is a bijection between $A$ and the enumarable set. I hope thats the correct reasoning then?